# How to set step in morris.js?

Tags: graphic, morris.js

I have a simple graphic on Morris.js:

[image]

How i can set a step in Y position? Step must be 50 points, e.q.:

...

150

100

50

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            new Morris.Line({
                element: 'myfirstchart',
                data: [
                {year: '2011-10-01' },
                {year: '2012', mark: 313.75},{year: '2013', mark: 323.75},
                {year: '2016-06-01' }
                ],
                xkey: ['year'],
                ykeys: ['mark'],
                xLabels: 'year',
                hideHover: true,
                labels: ['Mark'],
                ymax : 350, ymin : 0,
                events: ['2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'],
                eventLineColors: ['#aaaaaa']
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think you can do this is by setting the number of lines for the grid (numLines), based on your ymin and ymax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        new Morris.Line({
            element: 'myfirstchart',
            data: [
            {year: '2011-10-01' },
            {year: '2012', mark: 313.75},{year: '2013', mark: 323.75},
            {year: '2016-06-01' }
            ],
            xkey: ['year'],
            ykeys: ['mark'],
            xLabels: 'year',
            hideHover: true,
            labels: ['Mark'],
            ymax : 350, ymin : 0,
            numLines: 8,
            events: ['2012','2013','2014','2015','2016'],
            eventLineColors: ['#aaaaaa']
        });
});
</script>
```